# Resizing the jquery dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/6XVNr/2/ for a (not very sexy) example of the issue I'm having.

I wish to resize an iframe element which has been given the jQueryUI dialog treatment. The issue I have is that I'm not sure which element I should resize.. I can resize the id of the iframe which was targeted for the .dialog() function, or I can resize the resulting ui-dialog class, which wraps around the iframe.

Resizing the iframe element only affects the height of the dialog, the width is simply hidden by the dialog.  Resizing the ui-dialog class almost works perfectly.. the size is fine, but the buttonpane is not sticking to the bottom of the dialog.  Which is the correct method and how can I get it fully working?

Please ignore the colours, the scrollbars, the fact it's not centred after resizing etc.. I stripped everything out for the example - also tested with a div instead of iframe and got the same results.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it suddenly occurred to me - why not alter the height by resizing the iframe element, and the width by resizing the ui-dialog class.. seems to work ok so far :)